Differences between two definitions of limits (and colimits)
I am currently reading "Foundations For Almost Ring Theory" by Gabber and Romero and am currently a bit confused by their definition of a limit (and colimit) (Definition 1.2.10):
First given a small index category $I$, an arbitrary category $C$, and a functor $F:I\to C$ they define $c_X$ to be the constant functor $I\to C$ where each object goes to $X$ and every morphism to $id_X$. Then they say that a cone with vertex $X$ and basis $F$ is a natural transformation $c_X \to F$. This is all standard procedure and clear to me.
But now they define the limit of $F$ as a presheave on $C$ where $\mathrm{lim} F (X)$ is equal to all cones with vertex $X$ and basis $F$ and then for $f:X\to X'$ they set $\mathrm{lim} F (f)$ as the induced set theoretic map $\mathrm{lim} F (X')\to \mathrm{lim} F (X)$.
This definition above seems very similar to the standard definiton of a limit which is an object $\mathrm{lim} F$ in $C$ and a somewhat universal cone with $\mathrm{lim} F$ as its vertex and $F$ as its basis, such that for any object $X$ in $C$ there is an bijection of the set of cones with vertex $X$ and basis $F$ and the set of morphism $X \to \mathrm{lim} F$.
So my questions are if those two concepts are related? If so then how? And why do they define limits differently?

A limit is a representation of the functor of cones. Since the limit doesn't always exist, it is sometimes convenient to just speak of the functor of cones and treat it as the "formal" limit. This is justified by the Yoneda Lemma, an object may be understood by the functor it represents. This approach is in particular common in algebraic geometry where several constructions of schemes and algebraic spaces work better with the corresponding representable functors, but the constructions do not necessarily preserve the condition of being representable, or at least it requires a proof and it is useful to already have the functor in place.
